# plot quantiles 2.5% and 97.5% of AUC in R

Tags: r, polygon

I am trying to plot quantiles of AUC, here the code that I used:

```
 Q2.5 = c(0.3782141, 0.5578235, 0.8015502, 0.8191298 ) 
Q97.5 = c(0.3782141, 0.5578235, 0.8015502, 0.8191298 ) 
x  = c(0,3,6,9) 
plot(x,c(51.53,68.82,87.62,88.94), type="l", ylim=c(30,96), ylab="AUC") 
polygon(c(x,rev(x)), c(Q2.5, rev(Q97.5)), col = "gray")
```

I can not seen the shadow that expected to appear on the figure.
Any suggestion!

Comment: You mean the border? Maybe you should do the plot after the polygon, not before.

Comment: your y-axis goes from 30 to 96 and your y values for the polygon are below 1...

Comment: Oh I see thanks, @Cath